# How can I render html in a field in Blazor

Tags: html, blazor, rendering

I have a field saved in the DB with HTML.  I am using TinyMCE for my text editor and it is correctly saving the HTML tags in the DB. However, when I render the field, it still shows the tags.  Initaily I had this:

```
<td>
    @objInv.Notes
</td>
```

My latest attempt to resolve this is:

```
<td>
    @(new HtmlString(objInv.Notes))
</td>
```

Either way, it still renders as:

```
<p>New laptops 09/07/2022 <strong>test</strong></p>
```

What I desire is:

New laptops 09/07/2022 **test**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Blazor, rendering raw HTML is achieved using the `MarkupString` class. For instance, you can assign your raw HTML to a string variable and then cast it as a `MarkupString` when rendering. Alternatively, you can directly declare and initialize a `MarkupString` field.

Here's an example:

```
@tableTitle

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Notes</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>@((MarkupString)myNote)</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

@code {
    string myNote = "<p>New laptops 09/07/2022 <strong>test</strong></p>";
    MarkupString tableTitle = new MarkupString("<h1 style='color: blue;'>Laptop Notes</h1>");
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Raw HTML rendering in Blazor]

Comment: For reference you can also declare your field directly like this `public MarkupString content = new MarkupString("<h1>Hello</h1>");`